# ASP.Net MVC 4, Web API, and Passing Parameters Securely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

So I have been happily building my ASP.Net MVC 4 application for a month now.  I have the security model in place, users can log in and secure information is being stored in the users session for subsequent page requests.  This all works great.  I then implement some ajax calls to get additional data into the page.  I do this by making a call to a Web API interface.  In the Web API call I try access Session and low and behold Session is null.  Now I get that Web API is supposed to be "stateless".  All the parameters for a web api call should be passed in.  But what if some of those parameters are sensitive and can not be passed up from the client when making the ajax call?

I've read about the hacks to get access to session in WebAPI.  I would prefer not to do this and violate the tenants of web api.  ?
So do you store this information in the database and pull it out in the web api call?  Seem like a PITA to do that.
So how would could keep certain parameters secure when making the web api ajax call?
Or do you break down and just get access to session?

Answer (score 0):

Each service call could accept a user id.

The WebAPI controller method uses the user id to do further data look ups, such as looking up sensitive order details.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is inheriting from a Base Class, and this base class has the following:

```
public string UserName
   {
       get
       {
            return User.Identity.Name;
       }
}
```

The WebAPI can see this UserName and each UserName is unique, so you can do a user lookup based on this variable.

If you're wanting to send any further data to the WebAPI then you're going to have to send, say, an ID to the Controller and validate it against the UserName to see if they have access to it.

Psuedo...

I want a Policy!

Client side

- Sends Policy ID (1234 to WebAPI, meaningless to a hacker if they can't get info from it)
- This ID is validated against
  User.Identity.Name to see if information can be retrieved

Comment: I understand what you are saying and that could be done with a bunch of extra work to first write the session data to the database using a nondescript key and then pulling the data back out in the web api call using that same key.  Seems like over kill when the data I want is in session already.  Why does R/W to the database make it stateless but R/W to session is not?

Comment: Overkill would be passing data through that's already available in the db. An API has to be stateless, if you want all the methods to be coupled to a user session then use entity framework not an API model

Comment: @MikeMurphy surely your data is held in the database and can be accessed by an ID sent from the application to the Web API, so you can load this back up from the database from your API? It's awful practice to hold data this big in Session anyway.